# using winforms , mdi , parent and child form, opening child forms in specified space under the parent form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, parent-child, mdi

I have a winform MAINFORM , and need to open child forms in this form as shown in the image. The black portion is a panel & would contain a no. of LinkLabels and Treeview with multiple nodes. In the rest of the portion i want to display the child forms when the linklabels on the panel would be clicked.

The child forms should exactly fit into the remaining space i.e. space excluding the space covered by the panel.

Please help me out with the code, how to fit the new form in the left space.

Also, i would like to ask, that, shall i use the panel or is there some other control which could be more efficient or better here.
Also, does the MAINFORM needs to be made an MdiContainer?
[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 2):

Winforms already does this automatically.  You don't have to write any code, simply set the Dock property of the panel control to Left in the designer.  The darkgray MDI client area automatically shrinks to occupy the remaining space.  Any MDI child windows you create won't overlap the panel, they are constrained to the MDI client area.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a user control interface on the right docked to fill the remaining space, and each time a link is clicked I'd populate the control interface with a specific control designed for that link labels content.  That way you can forget about anything MDI related and for me at least, it would be a lot neater.

In a bit more detail, and a bit of a simpler way, basically everytime a link on the left is clicked, you create a user control that displays the relevant content for that link and display it on the right, docked to the main form so it fills the screen.

Then when another link is clicked, this control on the right is removed and the new one loaded.  Have a read about creating user controls and see what you think about this method.

Here's a link to get you started: [Creating and using Windows Forms Control Library (User Control) in C#.net](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/d1bc25c6-b686-4423-9cf0-147046d6e39d/?Creating%20and%20using%20Windows%20Forms%20Control%20Library%20in%20C%20Net)

To split the form into sections, take a look at the [Splitter control](http://en.csharp-online.net/Use_the_SplitContainer)

Comment: sir, can you please help me out on user control interface. that is, will i have to add it by going to the Project menu and then adding a user control from there, is this the user control about which you are talking about?

Comment: Yes its the same one you can add by going to the project menu, but a lot of this will have to be done in code. I'll update my answer with a bit more detail

Comment: sir, please mention the code also, would be a great help? also you din't tell about the panel which am using , shall i use it or not?

Comment: also , i want that the child forms which are displayed could not be moved and are fixed , like they are sticked into the left space.

Comment: sir, i did the way you said, i added a user control with dock = right and set formbackcolor= black. now on the form black portion i put a label and when i clicked it , a new form is displayed, but the form does not comes filled in the user control , its location is that it is half above the mainform's black portion and half above the user control. please guide me how to set the location of the new child form.