# Setting available region of MDI-Parent Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms, mdiparent

I have an `MDI-Parent` form name **`frmMain`** where I load lots of child forms in.

**frmMain** has a Menu on the top which covers a space about say 1000*25. When child forms load, they can be born in any location of **frmMain**, and sometimes they go behind the menu.

Is there a way to make **frmMain** think the space under this menu should not be used (Something like form region)? Or I should explicitly tell the child forms to be located below `height=25`?

[image]

the blue portion is a menu and above it, the red portion is a panel.

Comment: You have to dock your "menu" to prevent it from overlapping the MDI child windows.  Set the Dock property to, say, Top.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using winforms , mdi , parent and child form, opening child forms in specified space under the parent form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472485/using-winforms-mdi-parent-and-child-form-opening-child-forms-in-specified-s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is convenient for you, but you could add a `Panel/FlowLayoutPanel` to your Mdi window in the desired child forms space and add the forms to the panel like this :

```
Form frm = New Form();
frm.TopLevel = False;
frm.Show();
FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(frm);
```

Set the `FlowLayoutPanel.BackColor` to `Transparent` so it looks like an mdi container.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to do this you must set position pragmatically for each form or set their `start up` position to `center parent`.or simply use `Child.ShowDialog()` instead of using `Child.Show()`,with Show Dialog child window Is Focused until closed.